# Do ring dips and ring push-ups overlap?

Tags: strength, strength-training, gymnastics, rings

I'm getting a set of gymnastics rings soon, and will be modifying my current strength workouts to use them. I'm not at the stage where I should be doing ring dips yet, but from looking at ring push-ups, it seems that the two exercises overlap quite a bit.

Once I'm capable of doing ring dips, is there any point in doing ring push-ups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ring dips and ring push-ups definitely overlap; however, it will be beneficial to continue the push-ups after you able to do dips for a couple of reasons.

- Dips work your triceps more, while push-ups work the chest more.
- You will continue to be able to do more push-ups even when you can do dips, so you can start with dips and finish your work-out with push-ups.
- Variety produces adaptation. Doing both will give you more gains than only doing one.
- According to Ring Training for Elite Fitness ([Tyler Hass](http://www.ringtraining.com/)), though the two exercises are both "pushes", it is useful to alternate between them. This is because they operate in different planes: vertical (ring dips) and horizontal (ring push-ups).

A progression between the push-up and the dip would be to be vertical and use your legs a little bit for assistance (or get a rubber band to support some of your weight). Also, a similar exercise, which uses your shoulders more and is a progression for ring handstand push-ups, would be raising your legs a little bit above the rings.

Comment: If it's just a difference between difficulty and focusing on triceps versus chest, I'd be inclined to just do the more difficult one and use my ring-pushups time doing something unrelated on the rings. Does that make sense?

Comment: There is never enough time, so do what you think will get you to your goals fastest. But, when you have cool equipment like rings, I find it's fun to do a variety of movements. If you are looking for the hardest thing you can do, set strict muscle-ups as your goal.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to do both, since the upper body positioning for ring push-ups is similar to that in planche push-ups, which are a nice trick. In any case the more internally rotated elbows-in push-ups that are useful on the rings feel quite dip-like.

Comment: If my goal is pure strength and mobility for purposes other than gymnastics, would you still recommend them? I'm not currently working towards planche push-ups and I want to make sure my ring work is as  short and efficient as possible.

Comment: My hunch would be that ring push-ups are less essential, but if you plan to do push-ups, consider doing them on the rings. I know set-up and tear-down of the rings may be an issue.